# Cannot get Prometheus SD targets in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, service-discovery, prometheus-node-exporter

I have configured Prometheus Service Discovery:

**prometheus.yml:**

```
- job_name: 'GP'
    ec2_sd_configs:
      - region: us-west-1
        access_key: ...
        secret_key: ...
        port: 9100
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Name]
        regex: GP-.*
        action: keep
        # Use the instance ID as the instance label
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_instance_id]
        target_label: instance
```

And two instances are discovered automatically:

[image]

Metrics are also returned by both Instances:

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the pause duration of garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 7.296e-06
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 2.2649e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 3.5584e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 6.745e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.010453099
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.280941774
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 1405
...
```

Then I have added Prometheus as Data Source and Imported 1860 Dashboard, but no data is shown up while GP is listed as a Job:

[image]

I have also hardcoded Prometheus Job for testing purposes:

```
  - job_name: 'nodeexporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['xx.xx.xx.xx:9100']
```

And with this, it works:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Furthermore, Host values are always the same for both, `GP` and `nodeexporter`. Also, the other three Prometheus jobs (cadvisor, prometheus, pushgateway) are not exposed in dropdown, which is also confusing

Comment: i believe you are overriding the instance label using relabeling in the first example and it causes your dashboard to not return results in the query.

i suggest you check the query you have in grafana and how it works.
most likely the issue is in the dashboard query as you are able to scrape the metrics.

Comment: @Raven How to check a query? Where is it? I don't see it. I have removed relabel_configs at all and it works now. The other issue is strange Hostn names: b4b416082f5f

Comment: you can see the query a dashboard in grafana is using by clicking on the name and choosing edit.

Comment: Do you know how to fix hostnames?

Comment: it is hard to do remotely but i can try.
i will need to see the query you are using and the example of the metric in Prometheus.

Comment: I think this is done by this line: https://github.com/rfrail3/grafana-dashboards/blob/master/prometheus/node-exporter-full.json#L13629
Need to customize it.